# How do I rename a batch of files and move them to a new directory

Tags: powershell

This is what I've used so far to rename/move the files (separately)

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '8369','Name'}

Move-Item -Force -Destination 'M:\Destination Test Folder\'
```

How do I go about combining both tasks or using the Move-item task to move and rename the files?

Im fairly new to Powershell so I appreciate any assistance or insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the new filename in the destination parameter.

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object{
    Move-Item $_ -Force -Destination ('M:\Destination Test Folder\' + ($_.Name -replace '8369','Name'))
}
```